# CSS background color of individual rows

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I found many articles online about coloring alternate table rows. what about if I want use different colors for individual rows, how can I do that?

[image]

```
<table class="table1">          
<tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Surname</th>
   <th>Email</th>
</tr>                
 @{ foreach (var p in Model.People)
     {   <tr>
             <td>@p.Name</td>
             <td>@p.Surname</td>
             <td>@p.Number</d>
         </tr>
     } 
  }
</table>
```

Comment: Refer to this post. It's with jQuery but works - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540301/applying-a-random-background-colour-to-multiple-divs

Answer (score 4):

You can have in your css

```
.table1 tr:nth-child(1) {    background:blue;           }
.table1 tr:nth-child(2) {    background:red;            }
.table1 tr:nth-child(3) {    background:orange;         }
...
​
```

See demo
http://jsfiddle.net/wnCgL/

**Edit**

with jQuery, using a [random color function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484514/529725)

```
$(function() {
     $('.table1').find('tr').each(
        function() {
          $(this).css('background', get_random_color());  
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wnCgL/1/

Answer (score 3):

For example like this. Define some enumm or you can later generate colors by random:

```
public enum Colors
{
    Blue = 1,
    Red = 2,
    Yellow = 3,
    Pink = 4,
    Green = 5,
}
```

then in markup file get random color from enum

```
@{ foreach (var p in Model.People)
     {   <tr style="background-color:@(Colors[new Random().Next(0,Colors.Length)])">
             <td>@p.Name</td>
             <td>@p.Surname</td>
             <td>@p.Number</d>
         </tr>
     } 
}
```

**Update:**
Or if you want to make it more readable for users use [odd and even](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) css styles.

Comment: dont use this. either you define classes instead of inline-styles or go by the other solutions posted.

Comment: always divide structure and style! using inline-css, ad worst directly in a programming language is not usefull. if you ever want to change the styling, you have to edit your code.

Comment: It always depends on your goal. I agree with your statement, this makes code clear, but less flexible. Defining dozens of css classes isn't better solutions. In case of just colors inlining won't damage anything.

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r74j6/6/

Or this post - [Apply different background color using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905145/apply-different-background-color-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector `:nth-child`, but check it's [compatibility](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild#compatibilitysection).

```
tbody tr:nth-child(1) { background-color: #ffc000; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SK4dV/

For IE8 and below you can add style atribute or classes by JavaScript or when generating table add classes for every row and add some css rules for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically you have 2 options.

1) **Model Property** -  Put the class as a Model property for each of the people, that way you can assign different ones to different people.

2) **Pure CSS** - If you want the CSS route, just specify different colours for different selectors.

Personally, I'd go for number 2. Here's examples:

**Different Row Colours - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8exEZ/)**

For different row colours for each item, you'll have to do something like:

```
tr:nth-child(2)
{
    background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(3)
{
    background-color: blue;
}
tr:nth-child(4)
{
    background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(5)
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(6)
{
    background-color: orange;
}
tr:nth-child(7)
{
    background-color: purple;
}
```

**Alternating Rows - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8exEZ/1/)**

For alternating rows, just do:

```
tr:not(:nth-child(1)):nth-child(odd) /* excluding first row (header) */
{
    background-color: blue;
}
tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather fill td's background-color:

```
.table1 tr:nth-child(1) td { background-color: red }
.table1 tr:nth-child(2) td { background-color: green }
.table1 tr:nth-child(3) td { background-color: blue }
```