# Append another different classes to a set of similar class

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I want to append different classes to a set of repeating elements.

```
<div class="widget"></div>
<div class="widget"></div>
<div class="widget"></div>
<div class="widget"></div>
```

I want to style the above div elements by appending different style classes to them.

It should become like this

```
<div class="widget fg-white"></div>
<div class="widget fg-black"></div>
<div class="widget fg-red"></div>
<div class="widget fg-green"></div>
```

I know the direct CSS editing technique using jquery that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905145/apply-different-background-color-using-jquery) . But here, I want to append classes which already have the styles that I want.

Comment: your post is not very clear, can you provide a better explanation or a jsfiddle?

Comment: What if there is more than 4 elements? Have you made any attempts to achieve this yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var colors = ["white", "black", "red", "green"];

$('.widget').each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("fg-"+colors[i % colors.length]);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mmpjmr2v/)**

Answer (score 1):

You may use like this:

```
var klasses = ['fg-white','fg-black','fg-red','fg-green'];
$('.widget').each(function(){
   return $(this).addClass(function(i){
      return klasses[i];
   });
});
```